# Storing client's installed software information into MySQL using VB Script?

Tags: mysql, vbscript

I have a requirement of getting the installed applications informations into MySQL database, after searching in the net for hours I got vb script which is below. It should have two functionalities

1. it should save the data into a text file and
2. second is it should write into MySQL database.

I got the first one but for the second it is throwing an error

```
Object doesn't support this property or method : 'Execute'

code : 800A01B6
```

and code i have used is

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("c:\scripts\software.tsv", True)

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
  & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
  ("Select * from Win32_Product")

objTextFile.WriteLine "Caption" & vbtab & _
  "Description" & vbtab & "Identifying Number" & vbtab & _
  "Install Date" & vbtab & "Install Location" & vbtab & _
  "Install State" & vbtab & "Name" & vbtab & _ 
  "Package Cache" & vbtab & "SKU Number" & vbtab & "Vendor" & vbtab _
    & "Version" 

Dim objConnection
Dim objRecordSet
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
connectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=testing;User=root; Password=******;"
objConnection.Open  connectionString  

For Each objSoftware in colSoftware
  objTextFile.WriteLine objSoftware.Caption & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.Description & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.IdentifyingNumber & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.InstallDate2 & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.InstallLocation & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.InstallState & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.Name & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.PackageCache & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.SKUNumber & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.Vendor & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.Version

objRecordSet.Execute "INSERT INTO Computers (Caption, Description, IdentifyingNumber, InstallDate2,InstallLocation,InstallState,Name,PackageCache,SKUNumber, Vendor, Version)"&"VALUES (objSoftware.Caption & vbtab &, objSoftware.Description & vbtab &, objSoftware.IdentifyingNumber & vbtab &, objSoftware.InstallDate2 & vbtab &, objSoftware.InstallLocation & vbtab &, objSoftware.InstallState & vbtab &, objSoftware.Name & vbtab &, objSoftware.PackageCache & vbtab &, objSoftware.SKUNumber & vbtab &, objSoftware.Vendor & vbtab &, objSoftware.Version)", objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

Next
objTextFile.Close
objConnection.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the fact that the Recordset object has no .Execute method. In theory you should use Recordset.Open or Connection.Execute to execute a (parameter) query/statement.

Looking at the mess you made out of the `INSERT` statement, I advice you to `LOAD DATA INFILE` the .TXT data into your DBMS.

See:

1. [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)
2. [execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675023%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I am not trying to load the data from the text file to the DBMS. I am creating the text file as well as insert the data into the DBMS for each loop with the values extracted.